# How to turn off timeout in IIS debugging

Tags: debugging, iis

I have .NET application that is hosted on IIS 6.1
It is impossible to debug it for long time, because it is terminated after some period of time.

How to change to longer or turn off this timeout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you can do is change the **Connection Timeout** value using the IIS Manager. The default is 120 secs. You can change it to max integer value (to emulate turning off), yet 3600 (1 hour) is more than enough in my opinion.

Some links on the subject:

- [Did you know: Set Connection Limits in IIS 7 / 7.5](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Set-Connection-Limits-in-IIS-7-75.aspx)
- [Setting Connection Timeouts to Save Resources (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/31a2f39c-4d59-4cba-905c-60e7af657e49.mspx?mfr=true)